# Excel How to replace one part of a Formula in all the cells in a Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace `='Trial Balance'!E2+'Trial Balance'!E3` with `='Trial Balance'!C2+'Trial Balance'!C3` in Excel.

How do I change the formula in all the rows in a column from 'E' to 'C'?

I have written a VB Macro but I think it is wrong. Can somebody please correct it for me.

```
Sub RoundToZero2()
    For Each C In Worksheets("BalanceSheet").Range("BU8:BU103").Cells
        If E Then c.Value = C
    Next
End Sub
```

I also came across the `SUBSTITUTE` and `REPLACE` functions built into excel's formulas. Could I also use those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
Worksheets("BalanceSheet").Range("BU8:BU103").Replace "'!E","'!C"
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have no other Capital "E"s in your formula besides the ones you want to replace.  This will do it

```
Sub RoundToZero2()
    Dim formstr As String
    For Each c In Worksheets("BalanceSheet").Range("BU8:BU103").Cells
        formstr = c.Formula
        formstr = Replace(formstr, "!E", "!C", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        c.Formula = formstr
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, i would suggest, prehaps replacing '!E with '!C maybe. i think you can just do it on the complete range, so Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("BU8:BU103").replace "'!e","'!c"

Comment: I'm getting a subscript out of range? I have tried adding this to a macro with ctrl+q as a button, the error is:

Comment: @user2769025 my bad, I forgot to put your sheet name back in.  See Edit

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Great suggestion on the `!E`. I have incorporated.  I will need to test the whole range at once, you may be correct I have never tried it with formulas.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav please provide your full range replace as an answer.  It works and will be faster than a loop.